# SSH from tor on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to setup SSH tunneling using tor on Ubuntu 14.04

I have added the tor repo:

```
deb http://mirror.noreply.org/pub/tor lenny main
```

And installing the following packages:

```
  - tor
  - connect-proxy
```

And this is my .ssh/config

```
Host *
CheckHostIP no
Compression yes
Protocol 2
ProxyCommand connect -4 -S localhost:9050 $(tor-resolve %h localhost:9050) %p
```

But when I try to SSH to a host I seem to get this error

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/adithya/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/adithya/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec connect -4 -S localhost:9050 $(tor-resolve 192.168.0.10 localhost:9050) 22
debug1: identity file /home/adithya/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/adithya/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/adithya/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/adithya/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/adithya/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/adithya/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1000
ERROR: Got error response: 91: 'request rejected or failed'.
FATAL: failed to begin relaying via SOCKS.
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Can someone please help me trouble shoot this?

Thanks,

Comment: Check your `SocksPolicy` settings.
I've had the same problem, because my torrc contained default value of this entry (which is `accept 192.168.0.1/16`).
After changing the settings, ssh is working for me through tor.

Comment: First of all, check your Tor logs - is it "fully bootstrapped" for 100%? and - please post your `torrc` configs for the tor you're using on both sides - let's fix it!

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use `socat` instead of `connect`, using the following `ProxyCommand`:

```
ProxyCommand socat STDIO SOCKS4A:localhost:%h:%p,socksport=9050
```

No need to use tor-resolve, as, quoting the man page,

> In the command string, any occurrence of '%h' will be substituted by the 
>   host name to connect, '%p' by the port, and '%r' by the remote user name.

And I've verified that it indeed passes the name, as this works even when the `HostName` (not the `Host`) is a tor hidden service.

That being said, please note that I'm mainly using Gentoo, but I remember setting up this this command on Ubuntu, somewhere in 12.* (I don't have access to that machine any more).

Comment: I did try using socat. I am getting this error.


`2015/09/04 07:47:35 socat[1913] E socks: connect request rejected or failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`


Do i have to make any configuration changes for socat?

Comment: Now this looks like tor itself is not accepting connections (or is accepting them on a different port). Please check where tor is listening (`netstat -tlpn | grep tor`, possibly with `sudo` for `netstat`. Also check your tor configuration (it will either be `/etc/tor/torrc`, `~/.tor/torrc`, or if you use `vidalia` as well it will be `~/.vidalia/torrc` or something similar. Look for `SocksPort` `SocksListenAddress` and `SocksPolicy` in those files.

Comment: netstat shows that it's running on 9050 and the same in torrc value for SocksPort. I don't know whats causing the error. I have tired this before and it had worked now it's just not working.

Comment: @Adithya sorry for late response. Maybe firewall in that case? `iptables -L -n`. And have you verified that it's not listening on external address only?